# Why are these hashes of the same values different between different Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When hashing the same email address in two DataFrames, I am returned different hashes.

These two dataframes, df1 and df2, each contain a column of email addresses which need to be hashed, so the hashes can be compared when they are inner joined, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

### Boring part to import the data ###

# define table 1 as df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 'random.email@fjjd.com'], [6, 'different.email@u8888ueend.dskjs'], [7, 'random.email@dsju.c'], [8, 'same.email@dkicj.c'], [200, 'different.email@cjhs.oo'], [18, 'random.email@siidjd.dd'], [19, 'random.email@dsjds.j']])
df1 = df1.set_axis(['ID1', 'email 1'], axis=1)

# define table 2 as df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'new.email@jsscd.d'], [6, 'different.email@uueend.dskjs'], [99, 'new.email@djjsd.conm'], [10, 'new.email@jhhs.co'], [115, 'new.email@dsjjdsds.cod'], [116, 'new.email@dsjkjds.ckk'], [8, 'same.email@dkicj.c'], [200, 'different.email@jdsjd.co']])
df2 = df2.set_axis(['ID2', 'email 2'], axis=1)

### End part to import the data ###

### Fun part now... ###

# hash the emails in each row of df1?
df1['hash 1'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df1['email 1'].astype(str))  

# hash the emails in each row of df2?
df2['hash 2'] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df2['email 2'].astype(str)) 

# perform an inner join of df1 and df2 about their IDs, ID1 and ID2 respectively
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='ID1', right_on='ID2') 

# add an email comparison column
df3['same email'] = df3['email 1'] == df3['email 2']

# add a hash comparison column
df3['same hash'] = df3['hash 1'] == df3['hash 2']

# print the table...
print(df3)
```

The result shows that while the email addresses in row 1 are identical (as far as I can tell) the hashes are not the same:

```
   ID1                           email 1                hash 1  ID2                       email 2                hash 2  same email  same hash
0    6  different.email@u8888ueend.dskjs  18381560226251184406    6  different.email@uueend.dskjs  16113553761483526335       False      False
1    8                same.email@dkicj.c   5780217243550696535    8            same.email@dkicj.c   6939369575697951555        True      False
2  200           different.email@cjhs.oo  13252009090739560311  200      different.email@jdsjd.co   1942861278265138167       False      False
```

Why are these hashes of the same email address from different DataFrames different to one another?

Comment: Is there a reason using `pd.util.hash_pandas_object`? According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html) it works only on pandas objects. Why not using `df1["email 1"].apply(hash)`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely no reason, other than that it was what I read was a best practice. Your solution works for me, and if you are confident in its currency then please rephrase this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrejKesely and that my intention is ultimately to create a checksum of more row-values than simply email, to evaluate them together between DataFrames

Comment: I've posted an answer. The solution is to add `index=False` to not compute hashes together with indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html), the default mode of operation is including index in hash computation. So when two same emails have different indices, the hash is different.

You can try:

```py
df1["hash 1"] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df1["email 1"].astype(str), index=False)
df2["hash 2"] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df2["email 2"].astype(str), index=False)
```

Then the result will be:

```py
   ID1                           email 1               hash 1  ID2                       email 2                hash 2
0    6  different.email@u8888ueend.dskjs  5185970979410096600    6  different.email@uueend.dskjs  18338061231746973003
1    8                same.email@dkicj.c  9881121729072933860    8            same.email@dkicj.c   9881121729072933860
2  200           different.email@cjhs.oo   742268446511091656  200      different.email@jdsjd.co    775994242592712264
```

---

Other method of hash computation is using the built-in `hash` function:

```py
df1["hash 1"] = df1["email 1"].apply(hash)
df2["hash 2"] = df2["email 2"].apply(hash)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get different hash value for same values is because they have different index values. [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html) considered `index` by default.

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html):

> index: bool, **default True**
> Include the index in the hash (if Series/DataFrame).

You can look the source to further examine this.

In the function [`hash_pandas_object`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/util/hashing.py#L86-L175) they call hash function on the index too and combine the values of the index and values using [`combine_hash_arrays`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/core/util/hashing.py#L50).

```
def hash_pandas_object(
    obj: Index | DataFrame | Series,
    index: bool = True,
    encoding: str = "utf8",
    hash_key: str | None = _default_hash_key,
    categorize: bool = True,
) -> Series:
    
    ...
    elif isinstance(obj, ABCSeries):
        h = hash_array(obj._values, encoding, hash_key, categorize).astype(
            "uint64", copy=False
        )
        if index:
            index_iter = (
                hash_pandas_object(
                    obj.index,
                    index=False,
                    encoding=encoding,
                    hash_key=hash_key,
                    categorize=categorize,
                )._values
                for _ in [None]
            )
            arrays = itertools.chain([h], index_iter)
            h = combine_hash_arrays(arrays, 2)

        ser = Series(h, index=obj.index, dtype="uint64", copy=False)

    ...

    return ser
```

---

To just return hash values of the values make the `index` parameter `False`.

```
o1 = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df1['email 1'].astype(str), index=False)
# 0    2780788992335891103
# 1    5185970979410096600
# 2    1220693800013494134
# 3    9881121729072933860 # Same hash value for same.email@dkicj.c
# 4     742268446511091656
# 5    1378656245562222224
# 6     399519102630676222
# dtype: uint64

o2 = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df2['email 2'].astype(str), index=False)
# 0    14328170052497772172
# 1    18338061231746973003
# 2    13099453316458916481
# 3    12981085379025059893
# 4     2901278350923651293
# 5    13938198903035265270
# 6     9881121729072933860 # Same hash value for same.email@dkicj.c
# 7      775994242592712264
# dtype: uint64
```